# LNK2005 Error in CLR Windows Form

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I'm working on developing a Windows CLR form to create GUI interaction for some code I've been handling as a console program.

When I include the header in the console portion of the code, both of my headers play fine together, but when I try to include them in the *form*, they result in the following:

> librarytest.obj: error LNK2005: _SeqWait already defined in Gesture_Elicitor.obj
>
> librarytest.obj : error LNK2005: _KillDLL already defined in Gesture_Elicitor.obj
>
> librarytest.obj : error LNK2005: _SetSinFreq2 already defined in Gesture_Elicitor.obj
>
> librarytest.obj : error LNK2005: _ConnectDirect already defined in Gesture_Elicitor.obj
>
> librarytest.obj : error LNK2005: _GetDevice already defined in Gesture_Elicitor.obj
>
> librarytest.obj : error LNK2005: _SetSinFreq_Fine2 already defined in Gesture_Elicitor.obj
>
> librarytest.obj : error LNK2005: _Connect already defined in Gesture_Elicitor.obj
>
> librarytest.obj : error LNK2005: _TacOnTimeForTAction already defined in Gesture_Elicitor.obj
>
> librarytest.obj : error LNK2005: _SetSinFreq1 already defined in Gesture_Elicitor.obj
>
> librarytest.obj : error LNK2005: _GetLastEAIError already defined in Gesture_Elicitor.obj
>
> librarytest.obj : error LNK2005: _SetGain already defined in Gesture_Elicitor.obj
>
> librarytest.obj : error LNK2005: _Disconnect already defined in Gesture_Elicitor.obj
>
> librarytest.obj : error LNK2005: _ReadFWVer already defined in Gesture_Elicitor.obj
>
> librarytest.obj : error LNK2005: _SetSinFreq_Fine1 already defined in Gesture_Elicitor.obj
>
> librarytest.obj : error LNK2005: _SetSigSrc already defined in Gesture_Elicitor.obj
>
> librarytest.obj : error LNK2005: _ClosePort already defined in Gesture_Elicitor.obj
>
> librarytest.obj : error LNK2005: _ShowDebugInfo already defined in Gesture_Elicitor.obj
>
> librarytest.obj : error LNK2005: _OpenPort already defined in Gesture_Elicitor.obj
>
> librarytest.obj : error LNK2005: _DiscoverDevices already defined in Gesture_Elicitor.obj
>
> librarytest.obj : error LNK2005: _TacOnTime already defined in Gesture_Elicitor.obj
>
> librarytest.obj : error LNK2005: _PulseOnTime already defined in Gesture_Elicitor.obj
>
> librarytest.obj : error LNK2005: _tactorhandle already defined in Gesture_Elicitor.obj
>
> ....

The interesting problem is that one of my headers ("wiimote.h", from the WiiYourself project) works fine if its the only one included. The problem lies with "tactor_cHeader.h", which connects to its .dll . The abbreviated code in question is as follows:

```
#ifndef TACTOR_H_
#define TACTOR_H_

using namespace std;

#include <windows.h>

...

typedef int (*ConnectDirectPtr)(char*name, int type);
typedef int (*TacOnTimePtr)(int cidx, int board, int tacNum, int durMilli, bool returnifprocessing);
typedef int (*SetFreqPtr)(int cidx, int board, int freq, bool returnifprocessing);
typedef int (*KillDLLptr)();
typedef int (*SeqWaitPtr)(int cidx, int board, int waitTime, bool returnifprocessing);
...

ConnectDirectPtr ConnectDirect;
TacOnTimePtr TacOnTimeForTaction;
SetFreqPtr SetSinFreq1;
SetFreqPtr SetSinFreq2;
KillDLLptr KillDLL;
SeqWaitPtr SeqWait;
...

HINSTANCE tactorhandle = NULL;

inline int InitTactorDLL()
{
    tactorhandle = LoadLibrary("Tactor_DLL.dll");
    if (tactorhandle == 0)
        return -1;
    SeqWait = (SeqWaitPtr)GetProcAddress(tactorhandle, "SeqWait");
    ConnectDirect = (ConnectDirectPtr)GetProcAddress(tactorhandle, "ConnectDirect");
    TacOnTime = (TacOnTimePtr)GetProcAddress(tactorhandle, "TacOnTime");
    SetSinFreq1 = (SetFreqPtr)GetProcAddress(tactorhandle, "SetSinFreq1");
    SetSinFreq2 = (SetFreqPtr)GetProcAddress(tactorhandle, "SetSinFreq2");
    KillDLL = (KillDLLptr)GetProcAddress(tactorhandle, "KillDLL");
}

#endif
```

So what is it about this header that isn't playing nice with my form?

Comment: Can you also post the code (and the file name) where `SeqWait`, `SetSinFreq2`, `KillDLL` are defined?

Comment: I edited the original document to match your request @CristiFati . Does that help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry for the late reply.

The problem is simple, you have variable **definitions** inside your header file. Generally, a header file should only contain **declarations**. Check [[SO]: What is the difference between a definition and a declaration?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1410563/4788546) to see the difference between the two.

**To fix**, you should move these:

```c
ConnectDirectPtr ConnectDirect;
TacOnTimePtr TacOnTimeForTaction;
SetFreqPtr SetSinFreq1;
SetFreqPtr SetSinFreq2;
KillDLLptr KillDLL;
SeqWaitPtr SeqWait;
//...

HINSTANCE tactorhandle = NULL;
```

into the *.c* source file that really needs them, or make them ***extern*** ([[MS.Docs]: extern (C++)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/extern-cpp)).

#### Background

There are 3 phases when building *C* (*C++*) code into *Portable Executable code* (here I'm referring to *.exe* and *.dll* files). For more info, check [[MS.Docs]: Peering Inside the PE: A Tour of the Win32 Portable Executable File Format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms809762(v=msdn.10)):

##### 1. Preprocess

- Done by the preprocessor (*cl.exe*: [[MS.Docs]:
  Compiler Options Listed Alphabetically](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/fwkeyyhe(v=vs.100))) which is also the compiler (check next phase); this is by default a silent phase (you can see its output by specifying */E*, */EP* or */P* flags)
- For every source (*.c*, *.cpp*, *.cxx*, *c++*, ...) file, it handles all the *preprocessing directives* ([[MS.Docs]: Preprocessor Directives](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/preprocessor-directives)) (e.g.: *#define*, *#if*, *#include*, ...); the result is still a *.c* (*.cpp*, ...) file (different than the original, usually, significantly larger) also called *compilation unit* or *translation unit*
- When an ***#include*** directive is encountered, the line that contains the directive (there's only one file included per line of code) is simply replaced by the contents of the (*.h* or even *.c* (*.cpp*, ...)) file included. Note that this is done **recursively** (if the file included itself contains *#include* directives they are expanded as well, and so on). The original source file is much smaller than the preprocessed one, which is one of the preprocessor existence reasons

##### 2. Compile

- Done by the compiler (check previous phase)
- Every translation unit generated at previous phase is converted from *C* (*C++*) code (human readable) to machine code (*CPU* "readable") or *COFF format* ([[MS.Docs]: PE Format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/desktop/Debug/pe-format)). This is the *object (.obj) file* (its content is gibberish - at least at 1<sup>st</sup> sight), that can be seen in the *VC* project's intermediary directory
- Note that for each source file included in the project, after this phase there will be a corresponding *.obj* file

##### 3. Link

- Done by the linker (*link.exe*: [[MS.Docs]: Linker Options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/y0zzbyt4(v=vs.100)))
- All the object files from the previous phase are merged together (with a bunch of *.lib* files whose content is similar to *.obj* file's, but those can only be used indirectly - when building an **App**) plus some additional operations (e.g. adding the PE sections and headers, relocating some of the code, removing unused code, ...) into the final artifact of the project (the *exe* or the *dll*)

**Note**: this is *Win* specific, for *Nix* the phases are (almost) the same, tools differ.

What happens in your code:

- The file *tactor.h* (I'm assuming this is its name, based on the include guard at the beginning) contains a bunch of variable definitions; I'm taking `HINSTANCE tactorhandle` as an example
- Files *librarytest.c* and *Gesture_Elicitor.c* (got their names from the linker error) both *#include* (directly or indirectly) *tactor.h*
- At **Phase *#1.***, *tactor.h* will be expanded in both *.c* files (independently). So, both translation units will have ***tactorhandle*** variable
- At **Phase *#2.***, the 2 translation units from previous step are compiled and turned into object files, since their code is syntactically correct
- At **Phase *#3.***, when combining the 2 object files, the linker sees that *tactorhandle* is present in both of them, and then spits the errors above

**Notes**:

- You can also specify ***/FORCE:MULTIPLE*** option to the *linker* (by adding it to the *VC* Project *Properties -> Linker -> Command Line -> Additional Options*), but bear in mind that this might yield **unexpected results** (it doesn't even work for */clr* compiled projects)
- Since the project involves *.dll*s and functions import / export, you could also check [[SO]: Linker error when calling a C function from C++ code in different VS2010 project (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30583411/4788546), for errors that might appear when **using** this *.dll*

Comment: Thank you for such a thoughtful, informative response. It's a great help to better understand the context of my error.

Comment: The most important thing: Did it help you solving your problem?