# C - error LNK2005, _cmd already defined in complex

Tags: c, visual-studio-2017

I got this error when compiling my code in visual studio and i need help please :
`Error LNK2005: _cmd already defined in complex.obj`

I have the following C Files :

```
### File name: Main.c ###

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "complex.h"


int main()
{
    char command[30];
    int i;
    FOREVER 
        if (scanf("%s", command) == 1)
        {
            for (i = 0; cmd[i].func != NULL; i++)/*searcing the relevant function*/
            {
                if (strcmp(command, cmd[i].name) == 0)
                    break;
            }
            if (cmd[i].func == NULL)
                printf("Command does not exist: %s\n", command);
            else
                (*(cmd[i]).func)();
        }
}
```

and this:

```
### File name: Complex.h ###
#define FOREVER for(;;)

typedef struct complex
{
    double real;
    double imag;
}complex;


void read_comp(void);
void print_comp(void);
void add_comp(void);
void sub_comp(void);
void mult_comp_real(void);
void mult_comp_img(void);
void mult_comp_comp(void);
void abs_comp(void);
void halt(void);
void empty_string(void);
void stop(void);

struct STR{
    char* name;
    void(*func)(void);/*pointer to function*/
}cmd[] = {
    { "read_comp", read_comp },
    { "print_comp", print_comp },
    { "add_comp", add_comp },
    { "sub_comp", sub_comp },
    { "mult_comp_real", mult_comp_real },
    { "mult_comp_img", mult_comp_img },
    { "mult_comp_comp", mult_comp_comp },
    { "abs_comp", abs_comp },
    { "halt", halt },
    { "stop", stop }
};
```

and this:

```
### File name: Complex.c ###    
#include "complex.h"

    void stop(void)
    {
        exit(1);
    }

    void read_comp(void)
    {
        printf("read_comp\n");
    }
    void print_comp(void)
    {
        printf("print_comp\n");
    }
    void add_comp(void)
    {
        printf("add_comp\n");
    }
    void sub_comp(void)
    {
        printf("sub_comp\n");
    }
    void mult_comp_real(void)
    {
        printf("mult_comp_real\n");
    }
    void mult_comp_img(void)
    {
        printf("mult_comp_img\n");
    }
    void mult_comp_comp(void)
    {
        printf("mult_comp_comp\n");
    }
    void abs_comp(void)
    {
        printf("abs_comp\n");
    }
    void halt(void)
    {
        printf("halt\n");
    }
    void empty_string(void)
    {
        printf("Empty sting, Please try again\n");
    }
```

We have here some functions that get some parameters as inputs through the command line. The functions implementation is not finished yet.
Please i need help with solving the error.

Comment: Move cmd[] define out of header file, place it in your local c file, namely complex.c and access it by API

Comment: complex.h is a standard library header. Do not name your own headers the same thing as existing libraries, or you might get all manner of weird errors.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LNK2005 Error in CLR Windows Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34748913/lnk2005-error-in-clr-windows-form)

Answer (score 2):

Since you define the struct `cmd` in complex.h it will be instantiated in both object files, which then leads to the linking error.

You should define the struct only in one of the two files and *declare it extern* it in your header file.

This goes into your header file:

```
struct STR{
    char* name;
    void(*func)(void);/*pointer to function*/
};
extern struct STR *cmd;
```

And this for example in complex.c:

```
struct STR cmd[] = {
  { "read_comp", read_comp },
  { "print_comp", print_comp },
  { "add_comp", add_comp },
  { "sub_comp", sub_comp },
  { "mult_comp_real", mult_comp_real },
  { "mult_comp_img", mult_comp_img },
  { "mult_comp_comp", mult_comp_comp },
  { "abs_comp", abs_comp },
  { "halt", halt },
  { "stop", stop }
};
```

Comment: Hi Ctx and thank you for your answer, i got this error when correcting the the code as you wrote :
Error C2372 'cmd': redefinition; different types of indirection mman22 c:\users\sofi lt3\desktop\documents\visual studio 2017\projects\mman13\mman13\complex.c 3