# LNK2005 Error Related to OpenCV When Generating CLR DLL in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, .net, opencv, clr, linkage

Similar to [LNK2005 Error in CLR Windows Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34748913/lnk2005-error-in-clr-windows-form), yet this answer cannot explain what I've met.

**My question is at the end of the description, thanks for the patience.**

The project structure is as below (I simplify the situation to demonstrate the problem I met, which does not make any sense in real development):

Environment: Visual Studio 2019

Configuration: Debug/x86

OpenCV 420: I compile it to a dynamic library (.lib+.dll) myself because the x86 version is not provided officially.

**Project2: pure C++, output type: lib**

```
// ClassB.h
#pragma once
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
class ClassB
{
public:
    void FuncB();
};
```

```
// ClassB.cpp
#include "ClassB.h"
void ClassB::FuncB() {
    cv::Mat mat;
}
```

**Project3: C++ with /clr on, output type: dll for .NET Framework v4.6.1**

```
// ClassC.h
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
class __declspec(dllexport) ClassC
{
};
```

```
// ClassC.cpp
#include "ClassC.h"
```

Link against (**the input libs order matters**, will explain later)

1. `opencv_world420d.lib` (it's just an import library, at runtime use opencv_world420d.dll)
2. `Project2.lib`

And the compiler throws errors:

```
LNK2005 "public: __thiscall cv::MatSize::MatSize(int *)" (??0MatSize@cv@@QAE@PAH@Z) already defined in opencv_world420d.lib(opencv_world420d.dll)   Project3 (ClassB.obj)   1   
LNK2005 "public: __thiscall cv::MatStep::MatStep(unsigned int)" (??0MatStep@cv@@QAE@I@Z) already defined in  opencv_world420d.lib(opencv_world420d.dll) Project3 (ClassB.obj)   1
```

After some digging, I suppose it is because there're some inline functions in `mat.inl.hpp` header file which is needed by `class Mat` and included  by`opencv.hpp`(indirectly though), as below:

```
inline
MatStep::MatStep(size_t s)
{
    p = buf; p[0] = s; p[1] = 0;
}
```

Maybe the compiler decided not to inline the functions, but indexed them into `Project2.lib`, to assure, I dump the two libs:

```
// Project2.lib
8B6 00000000 SECT109 notype ()    External    | ??0MatSize@cv@@QAE@PAH@Z (public: __thiscall cv::MatSize::MatSize(int *))
```

```
// opencv_world420d.lib
??0MatSize@cv@@QAE@PAH@Z (public: __thiscall cv::MatSize::MatSize(int *))
```

As far as I know, `SECT109` and `External` do mean that Project2.lib has complete definition of `cv::MatSize::MatSize(int *)`, so do `opencv_420world420d.lib`

However, I explore 3 separate ways out to pass the compilation

**Solution 1**

swap the linking order to:

1. `Project2.lib`
2. `opencv_world420d.lib`

**Solution 2**

Turn the Project3 /clr off, make it a pure C++ project

**Solution 3**

Make`ClassB::FuncB`inline:

```
// ClassB.h
#pragma once
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
class ClassB
{
public:
    void FuncB() {
        cv::Mat mat(100, 200, CV_8U);
    }
};
```

```
// ClassB.cpp
#include "ClassB.h"
```

For solution1/2, I don't even touch Project2, so obviously `??0MatSize@cv@@QAE@PAH@Z` still exists in Project2.lib (so I don't understand how the compilation succeed).

For solution3, `??0MatSize@cv@@QAE@PAH@Z` disappears in Project2.lib (again I dumped the lib file and search the function name), so this does make sense to me.

**In conclusion, my questions are:**

1. Why solution 1 works, by just swapping the input libs order?
2. Why solution 2 works, by just switching off /clr for Project3 whose output target is dll?
3. OpenCV puts inline implementation in their hpp file, I wonder if it is a safe and good way to do so?