# Can I use opencv without .lib files?

Tags: opencv, dll

my code is to create .dll can work properly when I link with .lib files in properties. But I want to use .dll files only. Is this possible?

```
cv::VideoCapture cap;
    cap.open(0);
    if (!cap.isOpened())
    {
        std::cerr << "Error: Could not open the camera." << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    cv::namedWindow("Live Camera", cv::WINDOW_NORMAL);
    while (true)
    {
        cv::Mat frame;
        cap >> frame;
        if (frame.empty())
        {
            std::cerr << "Error: Blank frame captured." << std::endl;
            return -1; // Indicate failure
        }
        cv::imshow("Live Camera", frame);
        int key = cv::waitKey(10);
        if (key == 27)
        {
            return 0; // Exit successfully when 'Esc' key is pressed
        }
        else if (key == 'p' || key == 'P')
        {
            std::string picName = "picture.jpg";
            cv::imwrite(picName, frame);
            std::cout << "Picture captured and saved as '" << picName << "'" << std::endl;
        }
    }
```

I try to load opencv library using below approach, but then im stuck and dont know to code?is it possible to not use .lib?
[info] this code i use in my project to load the .dll library(that I link .lib files)

```
typedef int(*procCaptureCamera)();
    HMODULE dllHandle = LoadLibrary(L"myTestingLibrary.dll");
    if (dllHandle == NULL) {
        std::cerr << "Error: Could not load the DLL." << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    procCaptureCamera mCaptureCamera = (procCaptureCamera)GetProcAddress(dllHandle, "CaptureCamera");
    if (mCaptureCamera == NULL) {
        std::cerr << "Error: Could not find the function in the DLL." << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
```

I tried to create dynamic library. Its work fine when i link the .lib files. But when I remove the linker properties, I got this error

*Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl cv::Mat::~Mat(void)" (??1Mat@cv@@QEAA@XZ)   Testing C:\Users\Testing\Testing\dllmain.obj    1   *

any references to load opencv dynamically?

Comment: Why don't you want to use the *.lib* files? It's possible without them, but it's 10 times harder (and your code would look messy). Check [\[SO\]: LNK2005 Error in CLR Windows Form (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34777349/4788546) for details on build process.

Comment: maybe im not to understand in library. I try to make it explicit dynamic(i think).