# ifort: error #10037: could not find 'link' in Visual Studio

Tags: windows, visual-studio, dll, fortran, intel-oneapi

I have tried to run a Fortran code (.FOR) using Visual Studio 2019 and installed Intel OneAPI basic toolkits.
when I run a Fortran code I receive "ifort: error #10037: could not find 'link'". Does anyone know the solution?
Thanks.

Comment: I don't use Visual studio, but doing what I do whenever I get an error I don't recognize (pasting the error message into a search engine) gives many hits in this case. For instance do any of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33065962/ifort-error-10037-could-not-find-link , https://community.intel.com/t5/Intel-Fortran-Compiler/ifort-error-10037-could-not-find-link/td-p/1107597 or https://groups.google.com/g/cbfortran/c/XENYPPtcBDs help?

Comment: Welcome, please take the tour and read [ask]. Please do not use tags for [tag:isual-studio] and [tag:visual-studio-code] at the same time, they are two very different pieces of software.

Answer (score 1):

You need Microsoft Visual Studio configured to include C++ for Desktop Applications. See https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/guide/installing-microsoft-visual-studio-2019-for-use-with-intel-compilers.html for more details. You might need to do a Change/Modify of the Intel oneAPI HPC Toolkit (from the Windows Settings > Apps dialog) to get it recognized.

Comment: Thank you, Lionel. I followed the link and installed Desktop development with C++. I could run the code using Intel OneAPI Command Prompt.

Comment: If my answer solved your problem, please mark it as an accepted solution.